# Using both Python 2 and 3 in Vim (on Windows)

Tags: python, vim

I'm using Vim and lots of Vim plugins, on a Windows machine. Some of these plugins use Python 2, and some use Python 3.

I can use only one in the system %PATH% environment variable, how can I overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's Python integration (i.e. the `:python[3]` commands that most plugins use) does not depend on the `python` interpreter binary (from `PATH`); instead, Vim must have been compiled with the Python library(-ies), which you can check in the `:version` output (look for `+python`, and the `-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=...`).

To be able to use both Python versions, you need both `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`, and the corresponding DLLs accessible. You can check with the `:py` / `:py3` commands.

Comment: I've installed python at C:\python27\python.exe and C:\python33\python.exe. how can I add both these path in window system environment variable simultaneously?

Comment: Both installations should have placed their DLLs into the `system32` directory already. Or are you not concerned about Vim's `:py` integration, but rather launching Python from within Vim?!

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Neovim (a vim fork that rewrites the Plugin API) and this isn't a problem anymore.

https://github.com/neovim/neovim